# __repr__ and python unpacking

Tags: python, class, repr

I am attempting to print a players hand in a python project using classes.

(after much frustration I googled how do to this with unpacking)

is anyone able to provide an example of how I could use `__repr__` to simply print this list? instead of `__init__` can this be exchanged for `__repr__` ? is there another function that should be used to add the ability to print a list from a class?

for examples, why does the below work with unpacking but does not work without?

```
>>> print(*test_player.cards, sep='\n')
Ace of Clubs
King of Clubs
>>> print(test_player.cards)
[<__main__.Card object at 0x000001E2BA608388>, <__main__.Card object at 0x000001E2BA608488>]
```

the main body of my code is below:

```
suits = ('Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Spades', 'Clubs')
ranks = ('Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace')
values = {'Two':2, 'Three':3, 'Four':4, 'Five':5, 'Six':6, 'Seven':7, 'Eight':8, 
            'Nine':9, 'Ten':10, 'Jack':10, 'Queen':10, 'King':10, 'Ace':11}
class Card:

    def __init__(self,suit,rank):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank

    def __str__(self):
        return self.rank + ' of ' + self.suit


class Deck:

    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = []  # start with an empty list
        for suit in suits:
            for rank in ranks:
                self.deck.append(Card(suit,rank))

    def __str__(self):
        deck_comp = ''  # start with an empty string
        for card in self.deck:
            deck_comp += '\n '+card.__str__() # add each Card object's print string
        return 'The deck has:' + deck_comp

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.deck)

    def deal(self):
        single_card = self.deck.pop()
        return single_card


class Hand:

    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []  # start with an empty list as we did in the Deck class
        self.value = 0   # start with zero value
        self.aces = 0    # add an attribute to keep track of aces


    def add_card(self,card):
        self.cards.append(card)
        self.value += values[card.rank]

test_player=Hand()
test_deck=Deck()
test_player.add_card(test_deck.deal())
test_player.add_card(test_deck.deal())
```

Comment: The items in a list will be printed using `__repr__`, which is what happens in your second example. If you really want to change this, override `__repr__` for `Card`. (I don't recommend it, because it goes against the standard Python way of printing a list. Instead, perhaps override `__str__` for `Hand` where you print the cards, or add a `print_cards()` function to `Hand`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a `__repr__` in your `Card` class:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return str(self)
```

and then your `Deck` can simply do:

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.deck)
```

When you call `str()` with a list, it will call `repr()` for the individual elements of the list and format them with the familiar `[foo, bar, baz]` formatting.

Answer (score 0):

When you print a list, its repr includes the repr of each element, so create a `__repr__` method for your `Card` class. [The `__repr__` method should show info you can use for debugging](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__), and even better if it shows how to construct the object, so I would use this:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return f'{type(self).__name__}({self.suit!r}, {self.rank!r})'
```

So now we get this:

```
>>> print(test_player.cards)
[Card('Clubs', 'Ace'), Card('Clubs', 'King')]
```

I would also add a `__repr__` to `Deck`, though we can't show its construction, so I would use this:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return f'<{type(self).__name__}: deck={self.deck!r}>'
```

Now I get only the last two elements for simplicity, then check the repr:

```
>>> test_deck.deck = test_deck.deck[-2:]
>>> test_deck
<Deck: deck=[Card('Clubs', 'Jack'), Card('Clubs', 'Queen')]>
```

You could use something similar for `Hand`:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return f'<{type(self).__name__}: cards={self.cards!r}>'
```

```
>>> test_player
<Hand: cards=[Card('Clubs', 'Ace'), Card('Clubs', 'King')]>
```

BTW you might consider making `Deck` inherit from `list` to avoid the sorta clunky `Deck.deck`, and to let it directly support indexing, among other things.